# Creating a repeating notification with a receiver ( BroadcastReceiver )

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I have created a receiver that Extends BroadcastReceiver. This is used to execute my Notification that repeats daily, based on the time selected by the user. For some reason i cant get this to work. I am worried that i am getting the time from the number pickers wrong, but i am new to programing and could use some help. Thank you in advance. Let me know if you see any Errors.

Here is my main activity (MyActivity)

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

```
TimePicker timePicker;
Button setAlarm;
private int hour;
private int minute;
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
int AM_PM;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
    setAlarm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setUpAlarm);

    setAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setAlarm();
        }
    });



}

private void setAlarm() {


    int hour = timePicker.getCurrentHour();
    int minute = timePicker.getCurrentMinute();
    long time = 60 * hour + minute;



    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotifyService.class);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

    //create alarms
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);


    // AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY.
    alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);

}
```

Here is my Notification class ( extends BroadcatsReceiver )

```
public class NotifyService  extends BroadcastReceiver {
public NotifyService() {
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {



        //generate notification                                                     // should be splash activity
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MyActivity.class), 0);
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)

                .setContentTitle(null)
                .setContentText("Your tip for today is ready")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pi)
                .build();

    }

// dont forget to compile "com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+"



}
```

Here is my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />





<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".NotifyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
    </receiver>

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use a receiver with a filter in your android manifest. Create an 'explicit intent' instead of using an intent filter. This way,

Intent i = new Intent(your  random intent Action name).

This should fix you problem